# Is there a way to export all the layers properties in a PSD file into an organised "legend map" PDF file for the developers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ios

The design is ready inside a few PSDs and needs to be passed on to the developers. Is there an easier way to do it instead of manually creating it or giving away the PSD?

The end product should be a PDF containing the main layer (iPhone screen or webpage)
with relevant properties to each object. For example:

```
Back Button:
x:10
y:20
w:100     --------------- > Here will be an image of the object inside the main layer
h:123
Color: 20,50,20,1
Name: back_button.png
```

[image]

If such a tool doesn't exist, how do you pass the above data to the developers? Is there a common standard for this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any automatic way to do this (but would be interested in seeing one). However, I'd consider creating these resources in the language they are going to be used, especially if it's for web. It wouldn't take you long to write the styles so that devs only had to add the functionality instead of recreating everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[PNG Express](http://www.pngexpress.com/)** might be the closest thing you are going to find. I've never used it myself, so I can't really tell you how well it works...

At the bottom of the website there is a title: "*Create specifications fast and accurately*" which describes a feature similar to what you want.

There's also a **[video](http://vimeo.com/78187690)** at the bottom of the website, that shows it pretty well. The stuff you are interested in starts at about 40seconds in to the video.

[image]

---

On another note, there are photoshop plugins that export css:

- [Css3Ps](http://css3ps.com/)
- [Css Hat](http://csshat.com/)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. I will check all those in a minute. I'm still wondering, if you are not using any tool such as the above, how do you pass this data to a developer if you needed to? I'm trying to understand what is the standard approach.

Comment: I haven't worked in that way very extensively, as I can do both the design and the coding. **I'd probably have a meeting with the developer and discuss about what needs to be done, and what he needs to make that happen** ( which in your case could be just the psd file ).

Comment: I am the developer :)  Trying to help the designers..

Comment: @Sha I'm confused. Why would you make such an image for the designers? You are the one who needs this information, not them.

Comment: In iOS development, without a picture like the above, it would take me a lot more time to code a simple screen if I'll need to check every property of an object in a psd in order to get sizes etc'.

Comment: I'm not, I'm simply looking for an easier way for them (the designers) to create an image \ pdf like the above instead of doing it manually. PNG Express looks perfect for this.

Comment: @Sha I see. The way you asked the question made me very confused. -- This isn't necessarily a tool that the designer should use. I see it more as a tool for the developer, because as a developer, you are the one who knows what information is needed and what images need to be exported and in what way. -- I personally use Css Hat for information like width and height (I like it cause you can just copy paste it with css formatting) and I have a sublime text plugin that gives me the width and height automatically, when I create img element. I also use sprite sheet generators that give me the css.